# I'm using react-router-dom and created a fixed navbar that keeps changing size on each webpage and I don't know why

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router-dom, navbar

I'm using `react-router-dom` to make a multi-page website and I'm trying to add a fixed navbar to the top.

My navbar component and css file:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./NavBar.module.css";

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className={styles.nav}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? styles.active : undefined)}
            to="/"
          >
            Home
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? styles.active : undefined)}
            to="/Menu"
          >
            Menu
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? styles.active : undefined)}
            to="/Contact"
          >
            Contact
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

```css
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.nav a {
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: color 0.15s border-bottom 0.15s;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}

.nav a.active {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

I added the navbar to my website with this:

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar/NavBar";

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Root;
```

Basically the contents of Outlet is changing the size of my navbar. For example on the homepage the navbar is 690px wide but on the contact page its 710px wide. It appears the issue is with the size of the elements in Outlet because when I decrease the height the size change becomes less severe. But navbar is fixed so I'm not sure why Outlet is affecting it.

Here is my homepage component and css files:

```
import styles from "./Home.module.css";
import img from "../../img/spread.jpg";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Map from "../../components/Map/Map";
import HomeContact from "./HomeContact/HomeContact";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.home}>
        <div>
          <h5>Welcome to</h5>
          <h1>Spring Garden</h1>
          <Link to="/Menu">View Menu</Link>
        </div>
        <img src={img} alt="A table full of Chinese food."></img>
      </div>
      <HomeContact />
      <Map />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

```css
.home {
  display: flex;
  height: 60vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.home div {
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.home img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.home h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  margin-top: 0rem;
}

.home h5 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.home a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(205, 7, 30);
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: background-color 0.15s;
}

.home a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(231, 9, 35);
}
```

I'm trying to add a fixed navbar that won't change on every page of my website. However through inspect element I see that on each page the size of nav slightly changes. This causes my navbar to offset slightly. I don't understand why this happens because the navbar should not be part of the document flow.

The entire project is on github: https://github.com/iamgeeyuh/spring-garden-website

Here's a [running codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/iamgeeyuh/spring-garden-website) demo.

Comment: Hmm, 20px difference. Is the scrollbar popping in/out because different pages are rendering different content, some of it long enough to overflow the view and become scrollable? In my opinion there's not any issue here, but if you truly believe there is can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese is this a codesandbox demo? https://codesandbox.io/s/github/iamgeeyuh/spring-garden-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI doesn't have a consistent application of the CSS across the different routes that are rendered. I'd suggest specifying a more static layout in the `Root` component. Instead of making the `Navbar` position fixed use a grid layout to position the nav bar in the first row and then a scrollable content row that the `Outlet` and routed content is then rendered into.

Root

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar/NavBar";
import styles from "./Root.module.css";

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <NavBar />
      <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Root;
```

Root.module.css

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.scrollContainer {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Navbar.module.css - Remove the `position: fixed` and bottom padding rules.

```
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  /* position: fixed; */ <-- remove
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 0;
  /* padding-bottom: 1rem; */ <-- remove
}
```

[image: Edit im-using-react-router-dom-and-created-a-fixed-navbar-that-keeps-changing-size-o]

[image]
[image]
[image]